# Is a good practice to instantiate IQueryable query inside constructor

Tags: .net

Is it considered good practice to instantiate an `IQueryable<T>` predicate inside of a constructor (which uses dependency injection) so that the `IQueryable` base class is always defined?

I mean something as :

```
IQueryable<T> query;

public SomeClass(IRepository<T> repo)
{
    query = repo.GetQueryable().Where(c => !c.IsDeleted)
}
```

Then use the query statement inside some other function

Or it's best to do the query predicate init each time I use it?

Comment: Best answer I can give is... "It depends". It depends upon what you're trying to do, what are the other methods going to do? We would need more information to really answer this. Even then your question is likely to be largely dependent upon the answerer's opinion.

Comment: It's `IQueryable` (not "IQuerable") - you're consistently missing the "y" in `Queryable` ...

Answer (score 1):

The short answer: It depends

The long answer:

From a testability, performance and stability perspective; define a separate method for cpu and memory intensive tasks and keep the constructor simple and lightweight. Why? because it ensures that the object instantiation is quick and it does not throw any exceptions.

It also involves the topics of Separation of Concerns and Eager vs Lazy loading. Do some reading and do what makes sense to your particular use case.

Comment: It's just a preparation of a predicate... no code executed...